# passing the array inside a function

Tags: c

```
int f(int b[][3]);

int main()
{
    int a[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    f(a);
    printf("%d\n", a[2][1]);
}

int f(int b[][3])
{
    ++b;
    b[1][1] = 1;
}
```

`3x3 => 9` elements contained in the 2-D array `a`. When it's passed, then `b` will contain the the base address of the `a`. If suppose base address is `1000` then `++b` how does it to 3 locations and not 9 locations ahead? Are we doing typecasting when the variable `a` is passed to `b[][3]` as only the three elements?

How does `b[1][1]` correspond to the address of `8` and not `5`?

We can't do incrementing or decrementing in an array as array is a `const` pointer, but how is that they are incrementing `++b` as its an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function heading

```
 int f(int b[][3])
```

is a nothing more than a confusing way to write (and is *exactly equivalent* to)

```
 int f(int (*b)[3])
```

The type of `b` is "pointer to three-element array of `int`". When you increment the `b` parameter you adjust it to point to the next three-element array of `int` -- now it points to `{4,5,6}`. Then `b[1]` indexes once more and gives you the array `{7,8,9}` and finally `b[1][1]` gives you the oneth element of that array, namely `8`.

Comment: @henning... no words to the explianation... wonderfull... downvote.. please explain the reason... +1 for a nice explianation

Answer (score 0):

C multidimensional arrays are really linear, except that there is syntactic sugar to do the arithmetic correctly.

so with `b[][3]`, it excepts a 1-D array and implicitly translates `b[i][j] --> b[3*i+j]`

`++b` works as follows: `(++b)[i][j] = ORIGINAL_b[i+1][j]`.  So in your case, you are accessing `ORIGINAL_b[1+1][1] = ORIGINAL_b[2*3+1] = ORIGINAL_b[7]` (the 8th element)

Note: this is in stark contrast to the dynamic malloc version (in `**b`, `b` is a array of pointers)

Comment: C multidimensional arrays are really arrays of arrays.

Comment: You are thinking about `**b`, not `b[][]`

Comment: No, I'm thinking about `b[][]`.  A C multidimensional array is nothing more or less than an array of arrays.  (There are other ways to implement things that act like multidimensional arrays, such as arrays of pointers.)

Answer (score -1):

> How is b[1][1] corresponds to the address of 8 and not address of 5?

This is expected behavior:

```
int f(int b[][3])
{
    //at this point b[0][0] is 1, b[1][1] is 5

    ++b;
    //now b[0][0] is 4, b[1][1] is 8

    b[1][1]=1;
}
```

The pointer has incremented to point to the next memory slot, which is the second slot of array `a`. Basically:

```
b -> a[0]
++b -> a[1]
```